# Why am I receiving Opentok error OT_TIMEOUT "Session.publish :: Could not publish in a reasonable amount of time" in mobile safari over LTE?

Tags: mobile-safari, opentok, tokbox

I've created an application that leverages the OpenTok libraries. My calls to Session.publish in my application work perfectly when running on desktop browsers (the latest Safari, Chrome, Firefox browsers) over WIFI as well as while tethering to my iPhone over LTE. Calls to Session.publish also work perfectly on iOS Mobile Safari over WIFI.

The problem happens when I try to call Session.publish on iOS Mobile Safari over LTE or 3G. Is there any reason this shouldn't work considering it doesn't look to be a bandwidth issue, nor a networking issue (as it works when I tether from my laptop to the LTE network) ?

Note 1: I've performed the Tokbox precall test @ https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/precall/ and the connectivity to the "OpenTok Media Server" fails when running on iOS Mobile Safari over LTE. It's successful when running in every other scenario.

Note 2: I've also run the Tokbox playground tool @ https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/playground/ and I get a hanging loading icon in the video window when running on iOS Mobile Safari over LTE. It's successful when running in every other scenario.

Any help or thoughts on this is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be related to IPv6 enablement on the Rogers Network. I’ve had Rogers perform a workaround to switch back to IPv4 for my device and the error is no longer there. I had thought that the OpenTok SDK’s were IPv6 compatible but apparently they aren’t. I’m trying to contact Tokbox to have them address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact TokBox support for this. They will check the impacted session log at their end and let you know the root cause.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Chomu! I’ve contacted Tokbox but their response time is a bit sluggish. I’ve narrowed down the issue to something related to IPv6. Keep you posted on their analysis.